# Authentication to dropbox (login/passwd) with libcurl under c++

Tags: c++, dropbox, libcurl

I want to create desktop app that connects to dropbox (upload/ download files).
I am using lioauth for the authentication process and libcurl for handling http request 
under a C++ environment (visual 2010).

I still blocked in the authentication process! How can I insert my login/passwd to get the token and then use this parameter to call dropbox API?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't dropbox already do that themselves? Anyway, I think you need to give a bit more details about what you are doing, and what's going wrong. Sounds doable, so it's just a case of getting the bits in the right place and right order..

Comment: Thx for the  answer  orry I was little bit vague! I did some reasarch on google I found that I have to pass these parameters to libcul inorder to establish connection
string appkey = "<APP KEY>";
string appsecret = "<APP SECRET>";
string token = "<ACCESS TOKEN>";
string token_secret = "<ACCESS TOKEN SECRET>";

I have the 2 first parameters
and to get the 2 other parameters I think I have to send my  login/passwd in somehow
but right now I didt find a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should first make clear how to auth dropbox in firefox or chrome with debugger tools, it is not so easy to figure it out when facing obfuscated javscript codes, so you'd better first check if dropbox has openapi for developer.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way to access the Dropbox Core API is via OAuth. Users of your app will have to complete the OAuth flow in the browser to authorize your app. After they do this once, you can cache their OAuth credentials and keep using them.

Comment: Is there any way to fill login/passwd in the login web page automatically using libcurl (without user interaction)?

Comment: It's probably technically possible (since you can automate whatever a human would be doing), but we try as hard as possible to keep you from doing that, and it might violate our Terms and Conditions.

Comment: I am willing to create a client app that connect to dropbox using email/passwd. Is that violating your terms and Conditions?

Comment: That's not really something I can answer. Read the T&C and the developer guide for yourself. Just keep in mind that it's something we don't want people to do.